# What does the blue cross signify?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm feeling a bit silly for asking because I'm pretty sure the answer is very simple, but what does the blue cross next to credits signify on the Mission Computer screen (in game menu screen)?
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's your current amount of Medi-gel

The use of the logo is more obvious when you look at Medi-gel dispenser and Medi-gel boxes.
[image: Medi-gel dispenser]
[image: Medi-gel boxes]

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing, but just hadn't gotten around to asking yet. Thanks!